# 'isprint' returning true for a non printable character on solaris

Tags: c++, c, solaris

We have a character buffer which contains a stream of characters. We are reading each character at a time and checking it with `isprint`. While reading at some point `isprint` returns true for non-printable character. We printed the decimal value for that character - `-92` - but `isprint` is returning TRUE for this on Solaris.

#### Code:

```
for (int lix = 0; lix < l_len; ++lix) {
    int lch = l_buf[lix];
    if (isprint(lch) && !isspace(lch)) {
        fputc(lch, l_fp);
    }
    else {
        fprintf(l_fp, "\\%03o", lch);
    }
}
```

- `l_buf` is of type `const char*` and contains the stream of character.
- Data in this buffer comes through socket read.
- The very same code is working fine on AIX; i.e. `isprint` for a character on a particular index in the buffer returns `false` on AIX and `true` on Solaris.

Comment: Did you have the same behaviour if you use `unsigned char` instead of `char`?

Comment: either use unsigned or `if (lch > 0 && isprint(lch) && !isspace(lch)) {` or use `isascii()` (which also is non-standard)

Comment: What's considered printable depends on your current locale. You also need to worry about the signed-ness of `char`, which is implementation-defined.

Comment: From the comment in gnu's ctype.h: `ISO C requires that the ctype functions work for `unsigned
   char' values and for EOF; we also support negative `signed char' values
   for broken old programs.` In short: your program is not *supposed* to work for negative values, except for `-1` (EOF)

Comment: @joop [Indeed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isprint.html): *The `c` argument is an int, the value of which the application shall ensure is a character representable as an `unsigned char` or equal to the value of the macro `EOF`. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: "We are reading each character at a time..." and "Data in this buffer comes through socket read." --> this code is not shown.  The issues starts there.  To get a complete solution, show how input is read.

Comment: A quick fix is `if (isprint((unsigned char) lch) && !isspace((unsigned char) lch)) {`, but that may not get to the root of the issue.

Answer (score 8):

The behavior is undefined if the argument to the function `isprint()`, which is of type `int` isn't representable as an `unsigned char` or equal to EOF.

> 7.4 Character handling
>
> 1. The header  declares several functions useful for classifying and mapping
>      characters. In all cases the argument is an int, the value of which shall be
>      representable as an unsigned char or shall equal the value of the macro EOF. If the
>      argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 5):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isprint), "The behavior is **undefined** if the value of ch is not representable as unsigned char and is not equal to EOF."

It appears that EOF isn't -92 in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest change the type of `lch` to *unsigned char* and call the function isprint like this: `isprint(lch & 0xff);`
That should fix your problem because the man pages for *isprint* say that the function takes *unsigned char* on the input.
The `& 0xff` is not necessary but it is a good measure.

Comment: The `& 0xff` is not only unnecessary, but in error. Note that `unsigned char` might well have more than 8 bits (`CHAR_BITS`).

Comment: I'd say it can but it probably never will and even if so than you still want only the first byte of it as you want ASCII representation of a value which will always be in the first byte. So I would include it. But if you know something I don't I'd like to learn so please feel free to elaborate on this.

Comment: Consider a system that does only 32bit  addressing, and uses UTF32 encoding.

Comment: The ASCII representation would even fit in a septet. But from `-92` we know that it's not ASCII, so it's not really relevant to discuss how ASCII would have worked.

Comment: -92 is 0xA4 in normal terms, which is '¤' in iso-8859-1